# How to make a php or html page that you feed a word or two and it outputs the translated text

Tags: php, html, web

Basically my vision for a perfect version of this is:
Make a php/html page on my SMF forum, put some code in it, the page url will be something like www.myforums.com/translate-EnFr-hello%20world and when you open it it will show you a blank white page with the text "Bonjour le monde". I can find other ways of feeding the input, but I want the output to be as I specified.

Could anybody lead me on where to start/if its possible?

Comment: Your favorite search engine is the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Translate API to do that: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Comment: I have looked through it. Could you please tell me how do turn the big JSON format output into the translated line to appear on an html/php page?

Comment: Something like this: `$a = json_decode($string, true); echo $a['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];`